Preferred way to specify Task options in Gradle 8
I've seen many ways to pass options to a javac task in Gradle scripts. I was wondering, what's the difference between them (if any) and which is the preferred way doing this?
Directly via tasks. Does this affect all compile tasks with JavaCompile type? And we can access options directly without the need of configure and configureEach like the two examples below. Does this make this option a shortcut, and thus preferred?
tasks.compileJava {
    options.release = 17
}

Iterating, via withType and configureEach
tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.release = 17
}

Without configureEach, but this way, it seems we need to call configure inside:
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    configure(options) {
        options.release = 17
    }
}

Looks like the "generic syntax" (<JavaCompile>) is also accepted, and we don't need to call configure inside:
tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    options.release = 17
}

Finally, we also have the compileJava block. I know this only affects a single task, but which one?
compileJava {
    options.release = 7
}



You've listed five options for configuring the compile task in a Groovy build script, plus there's another important possibility I think you've overlooked.
Let's compare them:



#
Description
Code
Explanation
Recommended?
Docs




1
Eager single-task configure on tasks
tasks.compileJava {   options.release = 17}
Configures the task named compileJava, executing closure immediately
Good for brevity, but unnecessary code runs
Link


2
Eager single-task configure on project
compileJava {   options.release = 17}
Same as 1, but using Gradle feature where tasks can be referenced on Project object
Good for brevity, but unnecessary code runs
Link


3
Lazy single-task configure on tasks
tasks.named('compileJava') {   options.release = 17}
Same as 1, but only executes closure if the task is to be run
Optimal for configuring specific task
Link


4
Eager type configuration†
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {   options.release = 17}
Immediately executes the closure on all existing tasks of given type, and also executes later on all such tasks created later
No as unnecessary configuration runs: 5 preferred
Link


5
Lazy type configuration
tasks.withType(JavaCompile)    .configureEach {   options.release = 17}
As 4, but executes closure only if task to be run
Yes when configuring all tasks of type, or don't know specific name
Link


6
Kotlin DSL notation
tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {   options.release = 17}
This does not work for me in Groovy. It looks like the Kotlin equivalent of 4
No
Link



† In your question you suggest that it is necessary to call configure within tasks.withType(JavaCompile). This does not appear to be correct; I can configure the tasks fine without.

Wow! Thanks for such thorough explanation! I thought that tasks.compileJava configured all compileJava tasks, but I see now that it only configures one, and that there's another compileTestJava I'll need to configure as well. So I'll stick with #5 as suggested. Thanks!
